# Ionization energies of atoms while bonded

Tags: ionization-energy

Is the ionization energy of an atom different when it is in a bond or in a crystal?

For instance the ionization energy of H is 13.6 eV. Is it different when bonded with O in water? Another example is the ionization energy of Si in a crystal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not meaningful to speak of the ionisation energy of, say, the H atom within a water molecule because the electron is shared.

But certainly the ionisation energy of a water molecule will differ from that of an isolated H or O atom.

Comment: What about in an atom in a crystal?

Comment: @Adam look at the definition of ionization energy. Its is defined as the energy required to remove an electron from the outermost shell of an isolated gaseous atom (emphasis on isolated). Bohr's atomic model is only applicable for Hydrogen like species (containing only one electron). In a crystal or a other form, there surely exists some interaction like Van der waal interaction, that can deviate the value of IE.

Comment: @BhavyaSharma Ionization energy is defined for molecules too.

Comment: @Adam Yes, it will differ for a crystal versus an isolated atom as well. But once again, it's not meaningful to make a direct comparison.